# Extend templates with dataextensions/modules content - SilverStripe 3.4

Tags: silverstripe

I could add extra functionality to a dataobject if I extend it with a dataextension. For example I've got an Item which gets extended from a module with stock keeping functionality. Let's say the Item also gets's extended form a few other modules.

After the extension with the stock keeping functionality, I'd like to display the availability of the item in the frontend, for example with a green/red dot. How can I get this dot's markup inside my template for the detail page(ItemPage.ss) and the include (Item.ss) for the overview page of items **without** overwriting the whole template. Just adding this one part, like the way I extend a function on my base class?

Answer (score 1):

That could be a way to add extra markup to the original template.

**Inside dataobject or global dataobject extension**

```
  public function ExtraTemplateHTML($position) {
    $html = null;

    foreach($this->owner->extend('updateExtraTemplateHTML') as $positionBlocks) {
      if(isset($positionBlocks[$position])) {
        foreach($positionBlocks[$position] as $htmlBlock) {
          $html .= $htmlBlock->getValue();
        }
      }
    }

    return $html;
  }
```

**Inside the specific dataobject extension**

```
  public function updateExtraTemplateHTML($htmlBlocks) {
    $viewer = new SSViewer(__CLASS__);
    $html = $viewer->process($this->owner);
    $htmlBlocks['bottom'][] = $html;

    $topHtml = HTMLText::create();
    $topHtml->setValue(123);
    $htmlBlocks['top'][] = $topHtml;

    return $htmlBlocks;
  }
```

**Original Template**

```
$ExtraTemplateHTML(top)
...
...
$ExtraTemplateHTML(bottom)
```

**Extension Template**

Than just write a new template for your extension with the content you would like to add.

Comment: You are not overriding existing template, but actually changing the original to support extensibility. This approach is already used in packages `silverstirpe/widgets`, `sheadawson/silverstripe-blocks`, and `nobrainerweb/silverstripe-content-blocks`.

Comment: Cause it was never my goal to overwrite the templates - like described in my question. Thank you for the modules, perhaps their approach is better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot partially change a template, you can only substitute the template with another. So, keeping this in mind you should keep modular architecture with many logical includes.

Another possible way to extend existing content is using DOM and javascript. But you should think about side effects. For example if you add extra textual content then it won't be visible by crawlers and will effect your SEO. But for decorative enhancements, like adding extra coloured dot, this approach will work.

Comment: I suspected it isn't possible by default. The dot was only a simple example.  Of course there would also be more complex data to add. So JS wouldn't be a good choice. Perhaps I've to think about a custom function to achieve this.